# Creating an object (with a timer) inside a TidHTTPServer.OnCommandGet fails

Tags: multithreading, delphi, indy10, delphi-10.3-rio

Inside a `TidHTTPServer.OnCommandGet` I create a new object. This Object has a timer that should start immediately but doesnt. The TimerEVent never fires!
When I create the object somewhere else it works...

Some code

```
  TVolumeFader=Class(TObject)

...
constructor TVolumeFader.Create(...);
begin
  inherited Create;
  ...
  
    VolTimer:=TTimer.Create(NIL);
    VolTimer.Enabled:=FALSE;
    VolTimer.Interval:=100;
    VolTimer.OnTimer:=DoTimerTick;
end;

procedure TVolumeFader.DoTimerTick(Sender:TObject);
begin
  LogWrite('TimerTick in VolumeFader',Debug);
  If Assigned(VolTimer)then Begin;
    VolTimer.Enabled:=FALSE;
  End;
  try
    LogWrite('Executing VolumeFade in VolumeFader',Debug);
    VolumeFade;
  finally
    If Assigned(VolTimer)then
      VolTimer.Enabled:=TRUE;
  end;
end;


procedure TMain.OnCommandGet;

Begin;
  TVolumeFader.Create(...);
End;
```

Comment: It doesn't work because you create it and then set `Enabled := False` immediately afterward. It helps if you read your code. :-) The `OnTimer` event doesn't happen when the timer is disabled. You can find these sorts of issues pretty easily using the debugger to step through the code. You've also got typos in the code you posted, which tells me you didn't copy/paste your own code. Please do not retype code into your post, as it can easily introduce new errors that can be misleading or cause incorrect answers to be posted.

Comment: @KenWhite even if the timer were enabled, it still wouldn't work as shown, because the thread that the timer is created in doesn't have a message loop

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I missed it being an Indy related question. But the primary reason it isn't working in the code that the user posted above is that it's never enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your object's constructor, you are creating a `TTimer` ok, but you are setting its `Enabled` property to `False`.  So make sure you actually activate the timer once the constructor has exited.  Or else change `False` to `True` in the constructor.

That being said, your code still won't work as shown.  This is because `TIdHTTPServer` is a multi-threaded component, its `OnCommand...` events are fired in the context of worker threads that `TIdHTTPServer` creates for itself when clients connect to the server.  But `TTimer` is a message-based timer, it creates an internal `HWND` for itself which is tied to the thread that it is created in, and that thread must have a message loop in order for `TTimer` to process `WM_TIMER` messages.  The worker thread that you are creating your `TTimer` in does not have a message loop, so the `TTimer` will not be able to fire its `OnTimer` event.

So, you will have to either:

1. run your own message loop inside of the `OnCommand...` event handler after creating your object, and then free the object before the event handler exits. There is no guarantee that the calling thread will continue running once the `OnCommand...` event handler has exited.  Just note that the client will be blocked from sending any further HTTP commands to the server while the timer is running:

```pascal
procedure TMain.OnCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
  fader: TVolumeFader;
  msg: tagMSG;
begin
  ...
  fader := TVolumeFader.Create(...);
  try
    while (timer should keep running) do
    begin
      //Application.ProcessMessages;
      if PeekMessage(@msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) then
      begin
        TranslateMessage(@msg);
        DispatchMessage(@msg);
      end else
        Sleep(100);
    end;
  finally
    fader.Free;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

2. delegate the creation of your object, and thus its `TTimer`, to your main UI thread, so that your `OnTimer` event handler will be fired in the context of that thread rather than in the context of the server's worker thread.  Just make sure that your `OnTimer` code is thread-safe, if it needs to access anything that is shared with the server:

```pascal
procedure TMain.OnCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
  ...
  TThread.Synchronize(nil, // or TThread.Queue()
    procedure
    begin
      TVolumeFader.Create(...); // when do you destroy this object?
    end
  );
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Synchronize works perfectly!
@`Enabled`: Sorry for the missing code piece, `Enabled` is set to 'true' as soon as all callback events are set.
@`Destroy`: The object destroys itself after completing it's job.